# Method is called on other routers, Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a method (that detects when the tab is closed) that is called on created, on a component, but if I access another component , that method is still active.

```
created() {
  this.detectTabClose();
},

methods: {
    detectTabClose() {
      const onWindowTabClose = e => {
        var confirmationMessage = "o/";
        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; 
        this.submitBeforeCloseTab();
        return confirmationMessage;
      };
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onWindowTabClose);
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are setting up a event-listener on the `windows` object. So even though the tab is gone the listener is still there.

To fix this you need to "clean up" before the tab component is destroyed.

Just like `created` there is a life-cycle hook for this [`beforeDestroy`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy). In this hook you can use `removeEventListener` that takes the same function as input. To achieve this you move the function to `methods` (or elsewhere) where so that it can be referenced in both places.

```js
created() {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onWindowTabClose)
},
beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onWindowTabClose)
},
methods: {
  onWindowsTabClose(e) {
    ...
  }
}
```

An alternative method that uses a Vue event-listener with the `$once` method. `$once` works like `$on` but stops listening when the it encounters the first event that it listens to.

```js
created() {
  const onWindowsTabClose = (e) => {
    ...
  }
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onWindowTabClose)
  this.$once('hook:beforeDestroy', function () {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onWindowTabClose)
  })
},
```

The advantage of this approach is that your code is one place. This makes your components easier to reason about once they start to grow.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will be active - you bind it on window, which is global across all, well, window.

In order to prevent this behaviour, you need to `removeEventListener` when component is `destroyed`.